# How to configure different Ports on Ubuntu to Print?

Tags: networking, server, printing

I am new at creating a cups server and dealing with the different things that come with it. My problem is that I have an application that will only send to an ip address and port, but when I tried to use the cups port, it didn't do anything. I want to be able to configure a different port to send the file to a folder on my Ubuntu Desktop? Is there any tips or tricks to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea would be to try using the old-school `LPD` daemon (maybe this is the thing you need). `LPD` works on `TCP` port `515`.

For that, you would need the old good `inetd` installed as well.

Run this command:
`sudo apt-get install openbsd-inetd`

Then, edit the file /etc/inetd.conf and add this line to it:

`printer stream tcp nowait lp /usr/lib/cups/daemon/cups-lpd cups-lpd`

Then, restart inetd with:

`/etc/init.d/openbsd-inetd restart`

or

`service openbsd-inetd restart`

Afterwards, make your application print to the IP of your machine and port `515`. Note this will print to the "default" CUPS printer.

I hope this answer is useful. :)

Comment: It was weird, when I went and installed the lpd, it took off cups-pdf and cups stopped working all together. Is LPD suppose to remove cups-pdf?

Comment: Why did you install LPD? You just needed to follow the answer... :( I suggest you now remove the LPD daemon, install CUPS back and then just follow my advice (install inetd, configure it to use the cups-lpd filter); this will basically "emulate" LPD within your current CUPS installation. No need to install the old crap called LPD though - just inetd & a little trick to emulate LPD.

Comment: I did and had everything setup like you described before I installed it and after I removed it. It still wasn't pulling anything up. I made sure that both ends are setup correctly, but it still isn't working

Comment: What kind of application is it? Another option would be JetDirect style printing on 9100/tcp, but it would be good to know what that application is and what it expects in the "other end".

Comment: It is an old unix based application for printing reports

Comment: So, basically it should work with LPD. The question is if your inetd is configured as I described and if that LPD emulation works in your case. Aas well as if your app generated printer output in a way your printer understands. It might as well generate direct commands for some kind of a specific printer...

Comment: So, can you confirm that you tried the config where you have cups & inetd and no lpd and have that line in inetd.conf specified? And it didn't work when you specified the address of 127.0.0.1 and port 515 in your app?

Comment: I placed the code described above in the inetd.conf, no lpd is installed and I did specify the correct ip address and port 515. I made sure that I was able to print to the cups server through the regular way and it still works, but it will not accept the print job from the unix based application.

Comment: Alright. In that case, let's start from the beginning. :) In a terminal session, run this command: `nc -l 9100 > output.bin`. Note the directory you are running this in. Then, specify the output of your app to `127.0.0.1` and port `9100`. Do a print. Afterwards, you will have the "raw" printing output in the `output.bin` file and should be able to analyze what kind of data that is. I can help you do the analysis should you still be stuck.

Comment: It worked! Thank you! :) It sent the file to my home directory. My next step is to find where it sends the files when I print it

Comment: Exactly to the port you specify. I think, though, that you should next find out what kind of "raw" data this thing generates. Is it PostScript? Or some kind of output for a specific printer? It would be really good if you could mail me that output file. techblog (at) devlat.eu

Comment: After it is known what kind of data that is, I will be able to suggest what to do next.

Comment: I actually got it all figured out. I made a script that would run nc -l (port) > and print it out to a text file. Thank you so much Alvils for your help!

Comment: Good to hear that! Damn those old apps which do not know how to use CUPS! :)